# select multiple columns group by one column order by count

Tags: sql

I have the following data set in Oracle:

```
c1   c2   c3
1A2  cat  black
1G2  dog  red
B11  frog green
1G2  girl  red
```

Trying to get the following result.  Basically am trying to get rows with duplicate c1 first.

```
c1   c2   c3
1G2  dog  red
1G2  girl  red
B11  frog green
1A2  cat  black
```

Started with select c1 from t1 group by c1 order by count(*) desc, but not how to continue.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

This will work in almost all RDBMSs

```
SELECT  t.c1, t.c2,t.c3 
FROM    your_table t
JOIN(
        select c1,count(*) as cnt from your_table
        group by c1 )a
ON      a.c1=t.c1
ORDER BY a.cnt desc,t.c2,t.c3
```

## [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06a66/4)

Answer (score 0):

Getting all duplicates from column c1 can be achivied by simple ordering:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> ORDER BY C1 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select c1,c2,c3
from tbl
order by count(*) over (partition by c1) desc
```